# How to use Cron job in windows?

Tags: php, cron

I am new to cron job like things. I want to send email after regular interval (say 15 minutes). How can do it with using cron job. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: you can also use windows scheduler...

Answer (score 1):

Cron is a unix thing. You need to use windows scheduler - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I wan to do the same through PHP script, will it be possible?